How do I create a raster from points of soil samples in QGIS?
I have collected samples of soils from fields and have a GPS coordinates and soil test for element K, P and Mg for each of them. Now I would like to create a raster for each field based on the vector layer of points of sampling. For example there is 20 hectares large field with 5 points of sampling.
Is this possible in QGIS?

TIN-interpolation and then rasteration might work.

Another option is IDW interpolation

Interpolation is the key term, however you need to research the most appropriate interpolation method for your soil data. TIN and IDW are two, but there are others such as the various kriging and spline geostatistical methods.
